# Searching through a collection

Tags: c#, search, collections, return, generic-collections

1.The code snippet below is supposed to do search through a generic sort routine by the Title of a document and I am not sure whether it does this or not. Any Help?

```
public Document searchByTitle (String aTitle)
{
  foreach(Document doc in this)
  {
    if (doc.Title == aTitle)
    {
      return doc;
    }
    else
    {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

2.This code snippet is supposed to show a method returning the number of books stored on a collection. Does this make sense?

```
public static int NoofBooks()
{
  int count = 0;
  foreach(Document doc in this)
  {
   if (doc.Type == "Book")
   {
     count++;
   }
   return count;    
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you lloking for Linq? `public Document searchByTitle (String aTitle) => this.FirstOrDefault(doc => doc.Title == aTitle);`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko no no, it is supposed to be very simple

Comment: `I am not sure whether it does this or not.` what test's if any have you done? This is a simple debugging issue, if you debugged you would find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your code is *incorrect*, it should be:

```
public Document searchByTitle (String aTitle)
{
  foreach(Document doc in this)
  {
    if (doc.Title == aTitle)
    {
      return doc; // if we have found the required doc we return it
    }
  }

  // we've scanned the entire collection and haven't find anything
  // we return null in such a case
  return null;
}
```

Please note, you should `return null;` only after the *entire* collection is inspected.

Often we use `Linq` to query collections, e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...

public Document searchByTitle (String aTitle) 
{
  return this.FirstOrDefault(doc => doc.Title == aTitle);
}
```

**Edit:** The very same problem (*premature* `return`) with the 2nd snippet:

```
 public static int NoofBooks()
 {
   int count = 0;

   // scan the entire collection...
   foreach(Document doc in this)
   {
     if (doc.Type == "Book")
     {
       count++;
     }
   } 

   // ..and only then return the answer
   return count; // <- return should be here   
 }
```

Or again, put it as *Linq*

```
 public static int NoofBooks()
 {
   return this.Count(doc => doc.Type == "Book");
 }
```

Comment: Please don't succumb to this kind of behavior; op should be asking new issue's (*we can replicate*) on a new post, not adding more details that are irrelevant.